# Use App Access Token for ads stats?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api

I need to access Facebook API to retrieve ads stats. All my requests will be handled on server side. I already know how to access those data by obtaining User Access Token with `ads_read` permission, where user has admin role in the ad account.

My application will use cron jobs to retrieve ads stats, so I would like to use App Access Token instead, because user won't need to authenticate with the dialog, right? I assigned application to the business, but it doesn't seem to work. After trying to get ads stats with App Access Token, I'm getting following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The entity backed by id 1234567890123 cannot be seen
                by the viewer with (ViewerID 0, AccountID 0):
                DENY_RULE:InlinePrivacyPolicy:AlwaysDenyRule:4
                (EntID: 1234567890123)", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

The application is assigned to the business, but I'm not sure if it's enough. I don't see any option to assign it to the ads account.

Am I doing it right or maybe there's another way to skip dialog part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to use a [user access token from a user who manages the ad account](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/overview#access_token).

[App access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens) are only useful for a narrow range of use cases, primarily for updating app settings or proving a call came from the app specifically, rather than an arbitrary user of the app